# Find the equation of a system of coaxial circles of which the points $(\pm k,0)$ are the limiting points.

Tags: solution-verification, analytic-geometry

Find the equation of a system of coaxial circles of which the points $(\pm k,0)$ are the limiting points.

The definition of some terms relevant to the question in 2D geometry is as follows:

> The coaxial circles is the set of all circles such that any two of the circles have the same radical axis.

> The radical axis of two circles is the locus of the points which have the same powers with respect to them.(The power of a point with respect to a circle is the length of the tangents drawn from the point to the circle)

My solution goes like this:

> The equation of the radical axis  which is $y-0=0(x-k)$ and thus, $y=0.$ Now, we know that the limiting points and centres in a coaxial system of circles are collinear. Given, $(\pm k,0)$ are the limiting points, we can say, the centre of any circle in the coaxial system lies on the $x-$ axis. Thus, the equation of the point circles corresponding to limiting points $(\pm k,0)$ are $(x\pm k)^2+y^2=0.$ Thus, the equation of the system of coaxial circles is $$(x-k)^2+y^2+\lambda y=0.$$

Is the above solution correct? If not, where is it going wrong?

Comment: @AnneBauval I have added the definitions...By slope I mean the slope that it synonymous in 2-D geometry.

Comment: Thank you! I also learned the definition of [limiting points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limiting_point_(geometry)). Does [this page of MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CoaxalCircles.html) answer your question?

Comment: @AnneBauval I have edited my post. Mind taking a look at it?...

Answer (score 1):

Since $(\pm k, 0)$ are limiting points of the system, these two *point* circles  $(x\pm k)^2+y^2=0\tag*{}$ belong to the system.

Label their LHS as $S_1(x,y)$ and $S_2(x,y)$ then the equation of the system is $S_1+\lambda(S_1-S_2)=0$.

$$x^2+y^2+(2k+4\lambda k)x+k^2=0$$

Since $k\neq 0$, you might want to replace $2k+4\lambda k$ with $\lambda$ (because it's just a parameter).

$$\boxed{x^2+y^2+\lambda x+k^2=0}$$

[Visual graph for demonstration.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pt6ey09z6d)

Answer (score 0):

Your equation $(x-k)^2+y^2+\lambda y=0$ is not correct: the centers of these circles are not on the $x$-axis.

Following https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CoaxalCircles.html, the equation of a system of coaxial circles with limiting points $(±k,0)$ is:
$$x^2+y^2+2\lambda x+k^2=0$$
or equivalently
$$(x+\lambda)^2+y^2+k^2-\lambda^2=0.$$

Comment: But aren't circles in a system of coaxial circles have there centers collinear or equivalently upon a straight line?

Comment: Yes, this is why your equation was not correct: your centers were $(k,-\lambda/2),$ and $(-k,0)$ is not on this line. As you said yourself, since the limit points are on the $x$-axis, all centers have to be on this axis (not on the vertical line $x=k$). With MathWord's equation, the centers are $(-\lambda,0)$ and belong to the $x$-axis.